# Ejecutar función js despues de guardar datos en PHP

Tags: php, html, jquery, mariadb

Les comparto la funcionalidad que intento hacer. Tengo un formulario, con varios input y un input de tipo file para adjuntar un archivo PDF. Una vez que el usuario ha ingresado los datos y tiene el archivo que va a adjuntar. Presiona el botón de guardar, el código lo que debe hacer primero es guardar esos datos en la base de datos y posteriormente ejecutar una función js para guardar el archivo PDF en la nube. Lo que he intentado sin obtener buenos resultados es que después de mi codigo donde guardar los datos, incluyo una variable php, que a su vez la envío al html para que se ejecute la función. Sin embargo esto no sucede. Solo se guarda en la base de datos. Les comparto mi código html y php respectivamente.

```html
<div class="panel-body" style="padding:20px">
  <form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="estancias" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
    <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="institucion">Institución</label>
      <div class="col-sm-5"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="institucion" size="50" placeholder="Institución" required autofocus/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="fecha inicio">Fecha de inicio</label>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'><input type='date' name="fecha_inicio" class="form-control" size="50" required autofocus/><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="fecha fin">Fecha de fin</label>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'><input type='date' name="fecha_fin" class="form-control" size="50" required autofocus /><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="pais">País</label>
      <div class="col-sm-2"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="pais" size="50" placeholder="País" required autofocus/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="archivo">Adjuntar archivo PDF</label>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="input-group"><input class="form-control-file" type="file" id="file-upload" accept=".pdf" name="adjunto" size="50" required autofocus/></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php if(!empty($status)): ?><input type="text" name="confirma" value="<?php echo $status; ?>" onselect="return uploadFile()" />
    <?php endif;
?>
    <div style="text-align:center"><a name="boton" id="boton" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="" style="margin:10px" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span>Guardar</a></div>
  </form>
  <h2 id="results"></h2>
  <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message">Exitoso <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i>¡Ha quedado registrada la evidencia!</div>
</div>
```

Este es el de php

```php
    <?php  

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $institucion = $_POST['institucion'];
    $fecha_inicio = $_POST['fecha_inicio'];
    $fecha_fin = $_POST['fecha_fin'];
    $pais = $_POST['pais'];




    $errores = '';
    $status = '';

    if (empty($institucion) or empty($fecha_inicio) or empty($fecha_fin) or empty($pais)) {
        $errores .= '<li>Por favor ingresa la información requerida </li>';
    } else {
        try{
            $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=evidencias_dacsyh', 'root','');
        } catch (PDOException $e){
            echo "Error:" . $e->getMessage();
        }
        $statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM estancias WHERE institucion = :institucion and fecha_inicio = :fecha_inicio and fecha_fin = :fecha_fin  LIMIT 1');
        $statement->execute(array(':institucion' => $institucion, ':fecha_inicio' => $fecha_inicio, ':fecha_fin' => $fecha_fin));
        $resultado = $statement->fetch();

        if ($resultado != false) {
            $errores .= '<li>Ya existe una estancia en esa institución con las fechas ingresadas </li>';
        }
    }

    if ($errores == '') {
        $statement = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO estancias(id_estancia, institucion, fecha_inicio, fecha_fin, pais, id_usuario) VALUES (null, :institucion, :fecha_inicio, :fecha_fin, :pais,11)');
        $statement->execute(array(':institucion' => $institucion, ':fecha_inicio' => $fecha_inicio, ':fecha_fin' => $fecha_fin, ':pais'=>$pais));
        //header('Location: login.php');
        $status == "continuar";

    }
}

require 'views/estancias.view.php';

?>
```

Este es mi codigo para guardar archivo en Dropbox

```js
function uploadFile() {
      var ACCESS_TOKEN = ""; // Aqui va el access token key
      var dbx = new Dropbox({ accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN });
      var fileInput = document.getElementById('file-upload');
      var file = fileInput.files[0];
      var evidencia = document.forms[0].name;dbx.filesUpload({ path: '/3.Estudiantes/7.Movilidad estudiantes/7.2Productos obtenidos/' + file.name, contents: file })
        .then(function (response) {
        $('#loading').button('reset');
        $('#success_message').slideDown({ opacity: "show" }, "slow");
        console.log(response);
    })
        .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Fabricio, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. ¿Dices que quieres que el PDF se guarde en la nube? ¿En **cuál** de las nubes (Google Drive, Dropbox, Tu propia nube...)? ¿Cuál es el código que guarda el PDF *en la nube*?

Comment: Que tal Cedano. El código para guardarlo en la nube ya lo tengo y funciona sin problema, cuando yo llamo a la función directamente en mi formulario (onsubmit="return uploadFile()"). La funcionalidad que pretendo lograr es que primero los datos que el usuario ha ingresado en los input, se guarden en la base de datos y después se ejecute mi función javascript para que el PDF se guarde en este caso en Dropbox. El detalle que estoy teniendo es que solo se guardan los datos en mi BD pero no continua el proceso para poder ejecutar la función. Espero haberme dado a entender. Gracias

Comment: De todas maneras te comparto mi codigo para guardalo en dropbox

Comment: Stack Snippet sólo se debe utilizar para código HTML/CSS/JavaScript ejecutable directamente en la página de la pregunta.

Comment: Simplemente lo que tienes que hacer es, al final de la función que guarda en la base de datos, llamar a `uploadFile`. Tú la tienes actualmente en el `onselect` de un input. Si quieres que todo esto te funcione de forma transparente, si tener que recargar página, debes usar Ajax.

Comment: Gracias. Empezaré a aprender ajax. Nunca lo he usado. Un fuerte abrazo